# how to train a french NER based on stanford-nlp Conditional Random Fields model?

Tags: stanford-nlp

I discovered the tools of stanford-NLP and found it really interesting.
I'm a french dataminer / datascientist, fond of text analysis and would love to use your tools, but the NER being unavailable in french is quite puzzling to me.

I would love to make my own french NER, perhaps even provide it as a contribution to the package if it is considered worthy, so... could you brief me on the requirements to train a CRF for french NER based on the stanford coreNLP ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

NB: I am not a developper of the Stanford tools, nor a NLP expert. Just a lambda user that also needed such informations at some point. Also note that part of the information given below are from the official FAQ: http://nlp.stanford.edu/software/crf-faq.shtml#a

Here are the steps I followed to train my own NER:

1. Install java8
2. Create a train/test sample. It must take the form of `.tsv` files with the following format:

   ```
     Venez    O
     découvrir    O
     lundi    DAY
     le    O
     nouvel    O
     espace    O
     de    O
     vente    O
     ODHOJS    ORGANISATION
   ```

   Depending on the original format of your text, you can create this sample with SQL statement or other NLP tools. The labelling is the most complicated part as I don't know other ways to proceed than to do it by hand.
3. Train the model with this command:

   ```
   java -cp "stanford-ner.jar:lib/*" -mx4g edu.stanford.nlp.ie.crf.CRFClassifier -prop prop.txt
   ```

   where `prop.txt` is also described [here](http://nlp.stanford.edu/software/crf-faq.shtml#a).

   This should create a new `.jar` containing the newly trained model.
4. Test the model performances:

   ```
   java -cp "stanford-ner.jar:lib/*" edu.stanford.nlp.ie.crf.CRFClassifier -loadClassifier ner-model.ser.gz -testFile test.tsv > test.res
   ```

   The input `test.tsv` has the same format than the `train.tsv` file. The output in `test.res` has an extra column containing the NER predicted class. The last lines also show the summary in terms of precision, recall and F1.
5. Finally, you can use your NER on real data:

   ```
   java -cp "stanford-ner.jar:lib/*" -mx5g edu.stanford.nlp.ie.crf.CRFClassifier -loadClassifier ner-model.ser.gz  -textFile test.txt -outputFormat inlineXML > test.res
   ```

Hope it helps.

Comment: If anyone's looking for a french corpora, here's one with 200.000 entries https://github.com/EuropeanaNewspapers/ner-corpora/blob/master/enp_FR.bnf.bio/enp_FR.bnf.bio On an i7 with 16GB of RAM and SSD, it takes a little over 10 minutes to train