# Classpath Error when training a model with Stanford NLP

Tags: nlp, stanford-nlp

I get a classpath error when I want to train my NER model :

> Loading JAR-internal classifier
>   /edu/stanford/nlp/models/ner/english.all.3class.distsim.crf.ser.gz ...
>   Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Error loading
>   classifier from jar file (most likely you are not running this code
>   from a jar file or the named classifier is not stored in the jar file)

I'm using this command line :

java -cp "stanford-ner.jar:lib/*"  edu.stanford.nlp.ie.crf.CRFClassifier /Users/Desktop/austen.prop

I'm following the instructions from the Stanford NER FAQ http://nlp.stanford.edu/software/crf-faq.shtml

Someone know how to run correctly this command ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I fixed my problem, you need to use this command line :

> java -cp "stanford-ner.jar:lib/*" -mx4g
>   edu.stanford.nlp.ie.crf.CRFClassifier -prop
>   /your/path/austen.txt

You need to specify the absolute path to your property file to run your model.

For more details follow this good guide : [how to train a french NER based on stanford-nlp Conditional Random Fields model?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37852084/how-to-train-a-french-ner-based-on-stanford-nlp-conditional-random-fields-model/37918071#37918071)

Answer (score 0):

You're missing the [NER models](http://nlp.stanford.edu/software/CRF-NER.shtml#Models). If you include the models jar in your classpath in addition to what you have already, the command should work.

Comment: That's what I want to do with my command line: create a new NER model. Normally my command must create this model.